How to express ownership release in Swift 6 for pipeline of process
I have a heavily multi-threaded app that runs perfectly in Swift 5. I want to switch to Swift 6, and I got very few errors, but there is still this one I get and can't get rid of.
The code is transmitting a very complex data structure through a pipeline of processes, like this:
//  Can't be Sendable because of the need for mutable properties that will be modified
//  by Process1, Process2 etc...
final class ComplexData  {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

func Process1(lotsOfData: [ComplexData]) {
    for data in lotsOfData {
        //  Do complex things with complex data, and then give data to another process
        Task.detached {
            Process2(data: data)
        }
        //  I will never ever do anything more with data
    }
}

func Process2(data: ComplexData) {
    //  Do complex things with complex data, and then give data to another process
    Task.detached {
        Process3(data: data)
    }
    //  I will never ever do anything more with data
}

func Process3(data: ComplexData) {
    //  Do complex things with complex data, and I am done
}

I get error : Task-isolated value of type '() async -> ()' passed as a strongly transferred parameter; later accesses could race at each Task.detached line.
There is no data race because each ComplexData is accessed by one and only one Process at the same time.
In Rust this "access-time-exclusion" would be solved with "transfer of ownership". How to solve that in proper Swift 6 ?

You say that ComplexData “can't be Sendable because of the need for mutable properties”. One would generally just add some lightweight synchronization (e.g. a NSLock or OSAllocatedUnfairLock, and then once you have done that, you can safely mark it as @unchecked Sendable). (I would strongly advise against marking it as @unchecked Sendable without actually making it thread-safe.)

Unrelated, you really would be well advised to avoid these detached tasks (and unstructured concurrency altogether). If you’re open to feedback on that, let us know.

@Rob I agree that marking the data structure as unchecked Sendable would express something wrong, and would be a bad work-around, as we want to user to pay attention. I would also like to avoid adding complexity adding LSLock when it is not needed (I guess I would probably mess things up...).

@rob And yes, I would surely welcome a feedback on why detached task should be avoided as well.

Re avoiding unstructured concurrency, perhaps see https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/eb0771e5c96e1d36356f1cf0a49fe256.

I think the real answer to my question is in fact "don't try to map Swift Concurrency to the old thread management way".
Because of history, the current code is balancing the work over a number of threads and cores, when Swift Concurrency approach is to abstract the coder from that.
I encourage anyone to read and understand the Swift concepts of Isolation and Tasks, which, IMHO, are not that well explained in the official documentation (and in number of tutorials I found). This one helped me: https://www.massicotte.org/intro-to-isolation).
Because in my current code, I know for sure that there is no data-race problem, as thread are working on data, giving the result to another thread and then forgetting about it, I finally ended up doing the following:
I didn't wanted to mark complexData as @unchecked Sendable directly, so I used the following trick:
public struct PromiseToForget<P>: @unchecked Sendable {
    public let payload: P
    
    public init(_ p: P) {
        self.payload = p
    }
}

and I send this PromiseToForget from thread to thread.
I fully acknowledge this is no better, and doesn't help the compiler to help me, but at least, it reminds me that I must forget the payload once transferred.
I will have to make a deep refactor to make better use of Swift Concurrency.
Finally, I would like to thank @Rob for spending some time to explain me a few things. Well appreciated.


There is no data race because each ComplexData is accessed by one and only one Process at the same time

If you know that for a fact, then you can just mark ComplexData as @unchecked Sendable and let it go at that.

But I suggest that you read Apple's migration document which will give you a lot of detailed help with this situation. — The "transfer of ownership" feature you're looking for sounds like a non-Copyable struct.

Thanks, but as noted in Rob comment, using unchecked Sendable would express something wrong. I'll have a look at the link and non-Copyable.

@ AirXygène – I wasn't trying to say that “using @unchecked Sendable would express something is wrong”, in general. I was trying to say that it’s imprudent to do that without actually making the underlying type thread-safe. But if you do manually make it thread-safe (with locks or whatever), only then would you use @unchecked Sendable to, effectively, tell the compiler “don’t worry, I made it thread-safe and I’m vouching for that”. But it’s not generally prudent to use @unchecked Sendable just to silence a compiler warning if, in reality, you have not yet made it thread-safe.

@AirXygène  If you know for a fact that there is no data race then unchecked Sendable is correct. That is the thrust of my answer.
